# very odd 404 on wp-admin directory

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-404

I just moved my wordpress install from my older server to a new one which has CPanel installed. The site is working fine on the front end and if i am not logged in the wp-admin redirects me to the login page but as soon as i sign in i get a 404 error on the directory. i've checked file permissions, did a chmod recursivly to 755 then test if it would work if its set to 777 but it didn't so set back to 755. Apache log shows nothing useful except that it returns a 404 and i'm just really baffled because the front end is working fine...

has anyone ever encountered anything like this, can you suggest any way of trying to debug and get to the bottom of the cause and to fix it? its a wp 3.0.1 install on apache 2.2 with php 5.2.9 mysql 5.1

Not sure what else may be useful but ask and i'll provide what i can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue, CPanel had php compiled with Suhosin, i recompiled without it and everything's good.